# Are all variables inside a useEffect absolutely required to be listed as dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Do all variables used inside a useEffect always, absolutely, without exception need to be specified as dependencies?

My use case (simplified for demonstration purposes) involves different functions being executed depending on the width of the browser window, but not run when browser window changes:

```
const scrollToTop = () => window.scrollTo(0, 0)
const scrollToTopOfArticle = () => window.scrollTo(0, 200)

function App({
  isDesktop,
  selectedArticle
}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    isDesktop ? scrollToTop() : scrollToTopOfArticle()
  }, [selectedArticle])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{selectedArticle.title}</h1>
      <p>{selectedArticle.body}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I add isDesktop to the dependencies then the effect runs whenever the user resizes the window between mobile and desktop, which is not desired, but I'm also aware of the dogma that everything used inside the effect must be listed as a dependency.

Any suggestions on how to reconcile these two requirements?

Comment: It's a recommended practice, and not doing so will generate warnings, but it's not enforced by React, so feel free to disregard if you know for a fact that x value will never change, or whatever the case is.

Comment: The thing is that isDesktop could change depending on the user's behaviour. I just don't want the effect to respond to that change but only use that variable's value to determine what action to perform.

Seems like this should be a not uncommon requirement but I'm yet to find any examples documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make a `useEffect()` only responsive to a change in `selectedArticle`, use `isDesktop` and `selectedArticle` to initialize component states. Whenever `selectedArticle` changes, the first `useEffect()` will update both states with the passed-in props, and trigger the second `useEffect()` to re-run on the next render.

```
const scrollToTop = () => window.scrollTo(0, 0)
const scrollToTopOfArticle = () => window.scrollTo(0, 200)

function App({
  isDesktop,
  selectedArticle
}) {
  const [desktop, setDesktop] = useState(isDesktop)
  const [article, setArticle] = useState(selectedArticle)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (article !== selectedArticle) {
      setDesktop(isDesktop)
      setArticle(selectedArticle)
    }
  }, [isDesktop, selectedArticle, article])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (desktop) scrollToTop()
    else scrollToTopOfArticle()
  }, [desktop, article])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{selectedArticle.title}</h1>
      <p>{selectedArticle.body}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, you can abstract this latching behavior to another hook so that `isDesktop` only updates to its live value when `selectedArticle` changes. Note that `selectedArticle` still needs to be a dependency of the scroll action effect, so that the `useEffect()` will trigger the scroll action on every change to `selectedArticle` even if `isDesktop` has not changed values since the last trigger.

```
const useLatch = (value, deps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(value)
  const effect = useCallback(() => { setState(value) }, [value])
  useEffect(effect, deps)
  return state
}

const scrollToTop = () => window.scrollTo(0, 0)
const scrollToTopOfArticle = () => window.scrollTo(0, 200)

function App({
  isDesktop,
  selectedArticle
}) {
  const latchedIsDesktop = useLatch(isDesktop, [selectedArticle])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (latchedIsDesktop) scrollToTop()
    else scrollToTopOfArticle()
  }, [latchedIsDesktop, selectedArticle])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{selectedArticle.title}</h1>
      <p>{selectedArticle.body}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: In that example, if the component mounts when the user is in desktop then resizes to mobile, when the selectedArticle changes it will execute the desktop function.

Comment: @ChrisHalley does this look better?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I think you could be onto something there. I'll try that pattern in my real code and see how it goes.

Comment: @ChrisHalley I've tested the abstraction I wrote, seems to work as expected. Can you let me know if it works for you?

Comment: that abstraction is the most artful piece of code I've seen in a long time, and yes it works! Thanks so much for this. I'd been trawling the docs for hours looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

> Are all variables inside a useEffect absolutely required to be listed as dependencies?

Yes or else it will generate a warning.

That's why it's best to have clear idea what each effect should do (i.e separation of concern).

Thus, you can have two separate effects with different dependencies.

Something like:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    scrollToTopOfArticle();
  }, [selectedArticle]
);

useEffect(
  () => {
    if (selectedArticle && isDesktop) {
      scrollToTop();
    }
  }, [isDesktop, selectedArticle]
)
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph,

Problem is that in that first effect, scrollToTopOfArticle() will fire every time selected article changes, regardless of whether the viewport is desktop or mobile.

In the second effect, if a user resizes the window from mobile to desktop the scrollToTop() function will fire.